# Where can I sign up for updates on new google amp javascript releases

Tags: amp-html

Currently google amp project javascript is at version 0.1.

I'd like to receive notifications when new versions come out so I can keep my amp pages up to date.

Is there a place to sign up for such updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where they announce any updates and findings related to AMP: https://amphtml.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the roadmap on www.ampproject.org/roadmap/